# How can I tell if an item is duped in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I am a big fan of trading in TF2 and I have seen people report that some items in the game are duped, which considerably lowers the price of the item. Thus, I want to be able to know how to tell if an item is duped. Is there any easy way to find out?

Comment: Would you take a no? There are ways to find out, but they are anything but easy. Essentially, it involves checking against several backpacks and original id, all based on history. Since history is something kept by certain websites and has been cleared at times, there's very little reliability to be sure of a dupe. The idea would be to look for original id for the item (when it was first gotten) and check for other instances with the same, but with cleared/lost history, it's a weak test. [Here's a guide.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILrdi39a2IM)

Comment: What does DUPED mean exactly? and what is wrong with trading for them?

Comment: @Neffer_23 it means duplicated - fake, hacked, not legitimate, etc.  I'm not sure how it works in TF2, but in most games duped items will not remain yours forever and will eventually disappear because of their illegitimacy.

Answer (score 3):

The only "easy way" is to check an item's history on [www.tf2items.com](http://www.tf2items.com) or [www.tf2outpost.com](http://www.tf2outpost.com) if you use that site. After that it involves tedious backpack checking to see if the new owner has the item and if other people who owned the item still have copies of the same exact item (which is why you check the history). If the new owner has the same copy of an item previous owners still have, then most likely that item has been duped. Duped items are seen mostly in unusual trades. I would look at this: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Community_trading_tips, as it can prevent you from getting scammed and buying duped items.